# Two query in one main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two queries where i need to make a single query , only one conditions are different among them .

```
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(ISNULL(ChargeAmount,0)) AS CA 
 from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M CODES','SPP & LASH')
**and transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges')**
 and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'

    group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname

    order by [WeekEndDate]


    SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(ISNULL(PaymentAmount,0))  AS PA 
from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm 
where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
 AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M','SPP & LASH')
**and [TransactionType] in ('Payments','Adjustments')** 
and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'

 group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname

    order by [WeekEndDate]
```

THE output must be like this:[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation: As you are querying from same table:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(case when transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then ChargeAmount else 0 end) AS CA,
SUM(case when transactiontype  IN ('Payments','Adjustments') then PaymentAmount else 0 end) AS PA 
 from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M CODES','SPP & LASH')
and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'
group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname
order by [WeekEndDate]
```

Comment: I have another condition to find average of chargeamount; SUM(case when transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then ChargeAmount/COUNT(ChargeAmount) else 0 end) AS [Weekly Average];;; what is the exact format for this

Comment: what the condition is

Comment: just find average of chargeAmount as a seperate column

Comment: Try this - SUM(case when transactiontype IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then ChargeAmount/COUNT(case when transactiontype IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then 1 end) AS [Weekly Average]

Comment: how about AVG(ISNULL(ChargeAmount,0)) AS [Weekly Average] but i am afraid the condition for transactiontype ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') is not mentioned so output will come different

Comment: yes, you can use avg - just like avg(case when transactiontype IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') then ChargeAmount end)

Answer (score 2):

Join two IN clauses into a single IN clause and apply CASE logic in the calculation of SUM, so that you are calculating paymentamount and chargeamount separately.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype IN (transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') THEN ISNULL(ChargeAmount,0) ELSE 0 END) AS CA, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN transactiontype IN (transactiontype  IN ('Payments','Adjustments') THEN iSNULL(PaymentAmount,0) ELSE 0 END) AS PA
 from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M CODES','SPP & LASH')
and transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges', 'Payments','Adjustments')
 and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'

    group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname

    order by [WeekEndDate]
```

Comment: and transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges', 'Payments','Adjustments') these are two different condition

Comment: @RoverRoll, you wanted two queries into single query. two queries differer only in IN clause

Comment: i agree but for chargeAmount condition is transactiontype 'Charges' ,'Voided Charges'

Comment: @VenkataramanR, your modified query is just copy of my answer and you copied it wrongly

Comment: @fa06. sorry. I did not see your answer. I just modified the query.

Comment: then modified it correctly and explain it properly. And do you think CASE WHEN transactiontype IN (transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges') this syntax make sense of any?

Comment: @RoverRoll, Sorry. I originally did not see your two condition changes. as you told only one condition is changed, i got confused.

Answer (score -1):

you can join your both query

```
with cte1 as
(
SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(ISNULL(ChargeAmount,0)) AS CA 
 from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M CODES','SPP & LASH')
**and transactiontype  IN ('Charges' ,'Voided Charges')**
 and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'

    group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname

    order by [WeekEndDate]
), cte2 as(


    SELECT DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate) AS [WeekEndDate],
LocationGroupname,
SUM(ISNULL(PaymentAmount,0))  AS PA 
from [TransactionMasterReport]  as tm 
where tm.PostDate between '01/01/2018' and '02/03/2018'   
 AND MODALITY IN ('DRUGS','E & M','SPP & LASH')
**and [TransactionType] in ('Payments','Adjustments')** 
and locationgroupname like '%ABC%'

 group by DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, TM.PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),TM.PostDate),LocationGroupname

    order by [WeekEndDate]
) select cte1.* ,cte2.PA from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.LocationGroupname=cte2.LocationGroupname and cte1.WeekEndDate=cte2.WeekEndDate
```

Comment: if you kindly say to me reason of downvote that would be helpful